# Android 4.3 User Profiles Restrict Titanium Application To Access Database

Tags: android, sqlite, titanium, titanium-mobile, user-profile

i'm creating simple application that consume data from database.. I'm installing that application on the device and it works perfectly.. After that, i update my device OS to android 4.3 (my device is nexus 7) from update center and i try to use user profiles.. I create restriction user that only can open that application.. unfortunately, when i open my application it give me error

> No such table: [table_name] (code 1) while compiling [SQL_Syntax]

like that application can't find my table..

Does anyone know how to fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the latest version of the Titanium SDK? in the release notes they pointed out that they support Android 4.3

Comment: yes.. i've updated my titanium SDK to latest SDK.. But it still not solved.. do u have other solution? thanks..

Comment: What if you remove your app from the device and reinstall it? does it work then?

Comment: have you made any recent changes to the db? because I encountered this problem only when changing the db and installing over an existing app installation (without upgrading db)